# reset form fields previously populated with $_POST variables

Tags: php, jquery, html

I would like to just reset the fields populated with $_POST variables
which can be dropdown, textbox, radio etc..
because the usual html reset button cant do it

my jquery code goes like this

```
$("#resetBtn").click(function(){
  foreach($('#kensakuform').elements as obj)
  {
    if(obj.value)
        obj.value = '';
  }
});
```

it doesn't work and the tables i set with odd rows colored suddenly got conflict with this

Comment: What is `jQuery.elements`? Doesn't appear to be part of the spec

Comment: Why doesn't `$('#kensakuform')[0].reset()` work?

Comment: sorry i just assumed the foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#resetBtn").click(function(){
    $('#kensakuform').trigger('reset');
});
```

or

```
$("#resetBtn").click(function(){
    $('#kensakuform')[0].reset();
});
```

Comment: for unknown reason, my table with odd-colored rows suddenly lose its effect looks like it conflicts with other jquery codes

Comment: What are you using for odd colored rows in table?

Comment: my code jquery code is is '$(function(){
     $("tr:odd").addClass("odd");
});' and the css is '.odd
{
 background:#04B0C5
}'

Comment: there's no problem with the odd coloring sir, the problem is I tried the reset form suggestions here but somehow the odd coloring did not color

Comment: I hope the problem is fixed, if not post the complete/part code of that particular file.

Comment: i updated jquery version, but still the values inside textboxes arent cleared, maybe there some other way to deal with textboxes filled with POST variables?